# Can I capture values from a pattern synonym?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

Assuming a pattern:

```
pattern P :: [Int]
pattern P <- a:_
```

Can I *somehow* use `a` in the function `f`?

```
f :: [Int] -> Int
f P = a
```

The code above generates an error of `Not in scope: 'a'`.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is **no**, but if you give some more context why you want that perhaps there's an alternative approach.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I figured out a way that sort of does what I want, the specific case where I needed it was better solved by simply not using pattern synonyms at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is slightly embarrasing, but I found that just doing this works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern P :: Int -> [Int]
pattern P a <- a:_

f :: [Int] -> Int
f (P b) = b

main = print $ f [42]
```

The key point here is that the pattern parameter becomes explicit, but then it's also passed as an `b` pattern<sup>1</sup> which will be matched. I was missing this one piece of the puzzle.

The drawback is that obviously you need to enumerate all parts of the pattern you want to use.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course this can still be called `a`, I just named it differently for illustration.

Comment: You can also look at the support for named fields in pattern synonyms. I bet you could mix that with some record extensions to do almost what you asked for.

Comment: @dfeuer I briefly thought whether something like that might be possible, but couldn't figure out how it would be possible. But pattern synonyms keep twisting my brain anyways, so maybe I've missed something.

Comment: "you need to enumerate all parts of the pattern you want to use" - to me, one of the uses of pattern synonyms is to avoid enumerating all parts of a constructor and *only* enumerate the ones I want to use. e.g. `pattern Head :: a -> [a] ; pattern Head a <- a : _` for `safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a; safeHead (Head a) = Just a; safeHead _ = Nothing`

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, RecordWildCards #-}
module Temp where

pattern Cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
pattern Cons { car, cdr } <- car:cdr

safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead Cons{..} = Just car
safeHead _ = Nothing
```

This used to cause errors but [should work with recent releases of GHC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11987).

Bear in mind that `car` and `cdr` are defined globally as functions and shadowed locally via `RecordWildCards`:

```
ghci> :browse Temp
pattern Cons :: a -> [a] -> [a]
car :: [a] -> a
cdr :: [a] -> [a]
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
```